# Why is my boolean operator returning only false values inside a .map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issues with my boolean operator. I would like a div returned only if featured is true. My console log is showing false values, but true values are showing undefined.

```
{data.allContentfulProducts.nodes.map(product => {
        return (
          <Link
            to={`/shop/${pageContext.slug}/${product.slug}`}
            className={styles.featuredItem}
            key={product.id}
          >
            {console.log(product.featured)}

            {product.featured ? (
              <div className={styles.featuredSticker}>
                <p>Look I'm New!</p>
              </div>
            ) : null}

            <Img
              className={styles.featuredImage}
              alt={product.mainImage.title}
              fluid={product.mainImage.fluid}
              style={{
                position: 'relative',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
              }}
              objectFit="cover"
            />
            <h3>{product.title}</h3>
          </Link>
        )
      })}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `console.log` **always** returns `undefined`. It's a logging tool. It's return value isn't supposed to be useful.

Comment: I am not using the console log return for anything... I may have not explained myself correctly. Inside my .map I have a console log, logging the value of product.featured. False returns false, true returns 'undefined'.

Comment: @AaronDuke, for the console part, I believe it comes down to terminology, instead of `returns` it would be clearer to say `displays` or `shows` etc..  If console log shows undefined when it shows true, are you sure the value is actually true?

Comment: If it's logging `undefined` then it is `undefined`. Possibly you made a typo in the property name when you were trying to set it.

Comment: my graphQL is returning true values, that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Remove the `{console.log(product.featured)}` line. Does the code work as desired or not? If not, add `console.log(JSON.stringify(product, null, 2));` above the `return (` line, after the `map(product => {` line. Look only at the console, and see what the values are for the `"featured"` property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for that. Featured isn't coming through for some reason, ill have to figure out why.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(product, null, 2));` shows values only when featured = false. On true values, featured disappears completely from the console log.

Answer (score 1):

You can use && operator to return jsx expression only if it is true.

```
{product.featured && (
          <div className={styles.featuredSticker}>
            <p>Look I'm New!</p>
          </div>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting my cache solved this problem. Using Gatsby & Contentful.